# Cannot upload file: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYpUvDT' to 'var/www/libreria

Tags: php, file-upload

I already checked widely on SO and on the web but I was unable to sort this out and i'm feeling stuck.

This is the PHP code (it's pretty raw) i'm using to show an upload button for book files:

```
    $partpath = "var/www/libreria/lib-folder/";

 if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];


    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('epub', 'mobi', 'pdf');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 100000000) {
                $fileDestination = $partpath.$fileName;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                echo "Upload completato <br><br>";
            } else {
                echo "File too big <br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error with file: error code ".$fileError." <br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload this <br>";
    }

}
```

And I keep getting error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(var/www/libreria/lib-folder/Mongoose for Application Development.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/libreria/lib-folder/index.php on line 42

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpg36Ubt' to 'var/www/libreria/lib-folder/Mongoose for Application Development.pdf' in /var/www/libreria/lib-folder/index.php on line 42
```

I'm running an apache server on an Ubuntu localhost, and I already tried to do the following:

- setting permission of root foolder www/var to 777 and 755;
- setting ownership of folder to myself and to www-data;

I don't know what to check or do anymore to be honest, and I would be thankfull if somebody could give me an hint on what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks to anybody that will spend a minute to read and answer :)

Comment: just a guess, but it seems your origin is not existing: Warning: move_uploaded_file(var/www/libreria/lib-folder/Mongoose for Application Development.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. It seems, there is / missing, right before var :)

Comment: @corax228 man, thank you.
I guess that's why they tell you to not stay awake and code til late...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a guess, but it seems your origin is not existing: Warning: move_uploaded_file(var/www/libreria/lib-folder/Mongoose for Application Development.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. It seems, there is / missing, right before var :)

Comment: Here your deserved accepted answer, for being my eyes when mine weren't working :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems uploaded file has a filename that contains space characters. Try replacing all spaces in $filename with "_"  before calling move_uploaded_file.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but it turned out to be a path problem, as from reply above :)

Comment: Very good. I suggest corax228 adds it as an answer so it can be accepted!